# How to switch between CN1 CSS theme with Maven

Tags: css, maven, codenameone

just landed on this!! while searching on an issue with CSS theme switching between css files using Maven, here's what I did and please keep me right if I| overlooked something:

- I migrated successfully to Maven via [Steve's post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html)  using my existing theme.css,
- below is how I init my themes during the startup:

  try {
  resources = Resources.openLayered("/MailAngel");
  java.util.Hashtable vals = resources.getTheme(resources.getThemeResourceNames()[0]);
  UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(vals);

  ```
       Resources theme = Resources.openLayered( Constants.THEME_LIGHT );
       UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
       Resources.setGlobalResources(theme);

       //todo: get the device language
       initLocale();
       //init google nalytics
       //setAnalyticsService();     
   } catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       Log.e(e);
   }
  ```
- following the KitchenSink demo, I added a dark-them.css under the maven common/src/main/css folder, then I execute the code below:

  ```
    try {
       Resources resources = Resources.openLayered( "/dark-theme" );
       UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(resources.getTheme(resources.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));

       Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
       Utility.setTheme(theme);

   } catch(IOException e){
       ComponentUtility.showStatusError("Sorry, unable to switch theme: " + e.getMessage() );
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  ```
- Below is the the stacktrace when executing the above code:

  java.io.IOException: /dark-theme.res not found
  at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:756)
  at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:720)
  at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:684)
  at net.mailangel.pay.containers.ThemeContainer.update(ThemeContainer.java:111)
  at net.mailangel.pay.containers.ThemeContainer.lambda$getButttonContainer$0(ThemeContainer.java:58)
  at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
  at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
  at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
  at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
  at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
  at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3881)
  at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:5266)
  at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2409)
  at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1285)
  at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1203)
  at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
  at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

> My environment: Ide: Intellji Java: 8 Maven: 3.6.3 CN1: 7.0.80

Also, please note that, build.xml does not exists on my Maven project!,

Can you please advise with any hints on how:

- to switch successfully between css themes with Maven based CN project?,
- generate the .res file using the css?

Best regards,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I updated my post with the code and more info and hopefully inorder!

Comment: I've asked Steve to answer this. I'm not sure what's the status of dark mode support in maven. It's possible we need to update the dark theme post.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the dark theme is not yet supported by the Maven plugin.  I have filed an issue for this at https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3623